# Laravel. How to suspend user requests for a longer time after throttling limit is exceeded?

Tags: laravel, middleware, throttling

Laravel has native ability to control throttling of requests. Example is middleware `throttle:60,1`, which means 60 requests per minute to specific route. But is there anything to suspend requests if that limit is exceeded?

What I need?
i have 2 routes: 
`/lock` ==> this updates record with session identifier 
`/unlock` ==> this should unlock if correct password was sent, but if it has 5 attempts per minute with invalid password (`throttle:5,1`), then it should be suspended for 30 minutes, and each request should be rejected

Here we have dynamic throttling. Can i implement it using native laravel functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish whatever logic you want by extending the original `ThrottleRequests` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ThrottleRequests extends \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 2)
    {
        $original = parent::handle($request, $next, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes);

        if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes)) {
            // Do whatever you need to...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then edit your **App\Http\Kernel.php** to use your custom ThrottleRequests middleware:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```